# I have uploaded laravel project but its showing index of/admin. how to fix it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, admin, laravel-admin

I have uploaded laravel 8 project but its showing index of/admin in when I run the admin page.
Please help me.

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a bit more detail as to how you set up your laravel project on where you uploaded it to.  It's apparent that the webserver isn't setup properly as it shouldn't be showing the index.

Comment: You most likely didn't set the server's document root to the public folder. Hard to say without any more info. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). What server are you running on? Is reading  `.htaccess` files enabled? Is rewriting enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Add .htaccess file in project's root directory with content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's Not Working

Comment: As asked by @brombeer check if .htaccess file reading is enabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure you set default root folder to public.

If you using Apache you can rewrite with .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Nginx with this:

```
root /var/www/your_domain/htdocs/public;
```